# cannot make the iframe fullscreen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `Material UI` `Card` in my component to show a youtube video via an `iframe`. Everything is fine but I just cannot make the video fullscreen, it says `fullscreen is unavailable`

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4mm86xp0v)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const styles = {
 card: {
    backgroundColor: "pink",
    width: 680,
    height: 500,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  media: {
    width: 480, height: 360,
    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: "auto"
  }
};

const ImgMediaCard = (props) => {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          component="iframe"
          alt="Contemplative Reptile"
          className={classes.media}
          height="140"
          image="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ke90Tje7VS0"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ImgMediaCard);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material UI does not provide full screen feature in CardMedia component. But you can achieve it using alternate way. Please see the code below.

```
import React from "react";

import PropTypes from "prop-types"; 
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"; 
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card"; import CardActionArea from
"@material-ui/core/CardActionArea"; import CardActions from
"@material-ui/core/CardActions"; import CardContent from
"@material-ui/core/CardContent"; import CardMedia from
"@material-ui/core/CardMedia"; import Button from
"@material-ui/core/Button"; import Typography from
"@material-ui/core/Typography";

const styles = {   card: {
    // textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "pink",
    width: 680,
    height: 500,
    textAlign: "center"   },   media: {
    // ⚠️ object-fit is not supported by IE11.
    //objectFit: "cover",
    width: 480,
    height: 360,

    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: "auto"   } }; class ImgMediaCard extends React.Component{



  componentDidMount() {

    try {
      document.getElementById("iframeM").setAttribute("allowfullscreen",
"true")
      document.getElementById("iframeM").setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ke90Tje7VS0")
    } catch (error) {

    }

  } render() {   const { classes } = this.props;
     return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
    {}
      <CardActionArea>
      <CardMedia
          id ="iframeM"
          component="iframe"
          alt="Contemplative Reptile"
          className={classes.media}
          height="140"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>   ); } }

ImgMediaCard.propTypes = {   classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired };

export default withStyles(styles)(ImgMediaCard);
```

See above code, You can give id to CardMedia component, As CardMedia component does not add allowfullscreen attribute in iframe tag. So you need to do it manually, also its important to define src i.e source url for embed video manually, like i did as:

```
document.getElementById("iframeM").setAttribute("allowfullscreen",
"true")
document.getElementById("iframeM").setAttribute("src", 
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ke90Tje7VS0")
```

As iframeM is id for CardMedia component, And i am adding manually src, allowfullscreen attribute.

Also run this code on your local machine environment. I am attaching a video of tested code.
[Video of tested code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jO85dPvKlLSp3mLyL7a9mt1V9D0fgDpH/view)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have changed in newer material-ui versions. I was able to add the attribute

> allowFullScreen="allowfullscreen"

and it worked in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

```html
<CardMedia
    component="iframe"
    title="Your Title"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[your_video"
    allowFullScreen="allowfullscreen"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct attribute is-

`allowFullScreen="allowfullscreen"`

**Example-**

```
<CardMedia 
    component="iframe" 
    src={url} 
    allowFullScreen="allowfullscreen" />
```